# Access denied writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER in Python

Tags: python, windows, registry

I'm trying to update the user's PATH in Windows. I have a function similar to this one:

```
import winreg

def add_to_path():
    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE | winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE) as key:
        path, type = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, 'Path')
        path += ';d:\\'

        winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'OtherPath', 0, type, path)
```

This function fails on the call to `SetValueEx` with an access denied error. If I try to open the key with `KEY_WRITE` I get an access denied on the call to `OpenKey`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I missed the third argument to `winreg.OpenKey` - `reserved`, the way to open the key is:

```
winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment', access=winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE | winreg.KEY_QUERY_VALUE)
```